# bash netcat loop for simple webserver

Tags: bash, netcat

I trying to make a simple webserver using netcat. This is my code in bash:

```
port=5000
rm -f out
mkfifo out
while true
do
    cat out | nc -l $port > >(
        while read line
        do
            line=$(echo "$line" | tr -d '[\r\n]')  

            if echo "$line" | grep -qE '^GET /' # if line starts with "GET /"
            then
                request=$(echo "$line" | cut -d ' ' -f2) # extract the request
            elif [ "x$line" = x ] # empty line / end of request
            then
                sleep 3
                ./handle $request > out # this just returns response (http headers + content)
            fi
        done
    )
done
```

Index.html

```
<html>
<body>
   <h1>it works</h1>
   <img src="img1.jpg">
   <img src="img2.jpg">
   <img src="img3.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

When I open localhost:5000/index.html it waits 3 seconds then it loads the title and 3 broken images. After another 3 seconds it loads first image, then browser loading ends.

**Why it doesn't load remaining 2 images?** (if I open them separately in new tabs it works)

Edit: this is my custom netcat that I want to use instead of nc:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, newsockfd;
    socklen_t cli_len;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    char buffer[BUFSIZE];
    int option = 1;

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"usage %s [port]\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    bzero((char*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0)
    {
        perror("Error creating socket");
        return 1;
    }


    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
    {
        perror("Error binding socket address");
        return 2;
    }

    if (listen(sockfd, 10) < 0)
    {
        perror("Error on listen");
        return 3;
    }

    cli_len = sizeof(cli_addr);

    // while (1)
    // {


        newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr, &cli_len);

        if (newsockfd < 0)
        {
            perror("Error on accept");
            return 3;
        }

        if (recv(newsockfd, buffer, BUFSIZE, 0) < 0)
        {
            perror("Error on receive");
            return 4;
        }


        /* send request to bash */
        printf("%s", buffer);
        fflush(stdout);

        /* wait for bash response */
        int index = 0;
        int c;
        char output[100000];

        while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF)
        {
            if (write(newsockfd, &c, 1) < 0)
            {
                perror("Error on write");
                return 5;
            }
        }


        close(newsockfd);
    // }
    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your index.html isn't even a complete html, try adding `<html><body>` and `</body></html>` ?

Comment: that was just example, there are html and body tags but it has nothing with it

Comment: [tcpsvd](http://smarden.org/ipsvd/tcpsvd.8.html) is a much more appropriate tool for the job than netcat.

Comment: ...you could pull off a working implementation with [socat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/socat) too.

Comment: ...btw, if you want something to be efficient, you should avoid using external commands anywhere that's going to be invoked inside an inner loop or on a per-connection basis -- that means no `tr`, no `grep`, no `cut`. You don't need any of them if you're willing to use bash's built-in string manipulation primitives. Likewise, steer clear of subshells -- no `$()`, no backticks, etc.

Comment: (Correctly using either `socat` or `tcpsvd` will avoid all need for the FIFO-based hackery done here).

Comment: I want to replace nc with custom netcat later, but first of all it has to work with nc :) Then I might be able to understand how to change my own netcat.

Comment: You **can't** use `nc -l` reliably here without additional implementation-defined options allowing a single instance to stay open for multiple connections. Otherwise, any additional connections from the same browser made concurrently with the first one WILL FAIL when the first instance exits before the `while` loop gets around to starting the second one.

Comment: It is inherently the wrong tool. You cannot start with the wrong tool, "get things working", and then switch to the right one.

Comment: Hmm. Though, if you really want to go the hackery route, look into the necessary response headers to advertise pipelining support. If you got your browser to stuff everything into a single connection, your original `nc` code could be made to work.

Comment: Ahh! Now, if you're not using `nc`, that makes things easier. That said, why don't you look at the source to `tcpsvd`?

Comment: I updated my question with my own netcat that I want to use instead of nc. Currently it is working exactly like nc. It shows index.html but it loads just first image. I will take a look thanks.

Comment: Understood, but right now this is really beyond a single question's reasonable scope. Do you want to know how to write a superserver (such as tcpsvd, xinetd, etc)? Then it doesn't need to be a bash question at all. Do you want to know how to write a bash script that groks HTTP? Then it doesn't need to know how superservers work, it just needs to use and depend on one. If you need an introduction to both sets of topics, it really should be more than one question.

Comment: (actually, systemd contains a superserver too, so if you're on an operating system that offers it, you can use that instead of tcpsvd/inetd/etc as an additional option; see http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/inetd.html)

Comment: No I don't want to write super server just a simple server that will load that example html file. No other functions.

Comment: Let's be clear: "superserver" is a term of the art: It's a service that runs other services, including holding listen sockets open, spawning new processes attached to those sockets when a connection comes in, and optionally pre-spawning processes to be able to deal with multiple inbound connections very quickly. Most operating systems come with one already. Part of my point is that you should be using that operating-system facility, not reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Well, it's just for a learning purposes. That's why it should support just opening connection and sending required files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128381/discussion-between-donthavename-and-charles-duffy).

Answer (score 0):

`nc` is inherently unsuited to scenarios when you need to process multiple concurrent connections, as is the case here, and to ensure that the listen socket is not even transiently closed between such multiple connections.

---

Assuming that you have a `handle-conn` program written as such:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
request=
while IFS= read -r line; do
  if [[ $line = "GET /"* ]]; then
    request=${line#* } # delete everything up to first space in $line
  elif [[ $request ]] && [[ -z $line ]]; then
    ./handle "$request"
    request= # clear request until another GET is seen
  fi
done
```

...with your existing `handle` helper (which really should be inlined for performance reasons), then you can use `tcpsvd` as follows:

```
tcpsvd 0.0.0.0 5000 ./handler
```